# A media player that leaves no trace in user profile

Tags: media-player, portable

I use [MPC-HC](https://mpc-hc.org/) which has a portable version, it works just fine. The problem is that it creates folder in the user's profile like **MPC-HC** in *AppData\Roaming*. I need a similar player that plays all files without modifying any folders except the one in which it is extracted because I need to be able to play videos that I might get on server which does not have the windows store apps.

Comment: Afaik, all programs from https://portableapps.com/ write only to the program's directory. I like VLC, but you ought to be able to use anything form there.